# Lua: getting environment of element that belongs to specified table

Tags: lua

Is it possible to check if some object is really element of specified table? I tried to use `debug.getfenv(o)` but didn't work.

```
someTable = {}
someTable.someValue = "Some String"

--gettable(someTable.someValue)
--so that could return table that stores someValue: someTable
```

Comment: What are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getfenv` is so named because it returns a *function*'s environment. Because only functions *have* environments.

Values in Lua have no particular knowledge of which tables that they're in. If you need to know that, you'll have to keep track of it yourself.